# Swift 2 add protocol conformance to protocols

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2

Can I add protocol conformance to a protocol via a swift extension?

```
//Plain old protocol here
protocol MyData {
    var myDataID: Int { get }
}
```

I want to make the `MyData` protocol equatable by default (just compare the ID)

```
extension MyData : Equatable { }
```

But I get this lovely error:

> "Extension of protocol 'MyData' cannot have an inheritance clause"

The behavior i'm looking is BananaData conforming to Equatable (a protocol) because it implements the MyData protocol which can provide a default implementation of Equatable

```
//This is the method to implement Equatable
func ==(lhs: MyData, rhs: MyData) -> Bool {
    return lhs.myDataID == rhs.myDataID
}

struct BananaData: MyData {
    var myDataID: Int = 1
}

func checkEquatable(bananaOne: BananaData, bananaTwo: BananaData) {
    //This compiles, verifying that BananaData can be compared
    if bananaOne == bananaTwo { }
    //But BananaData is not convertible to Equatable, which is what I want
    let equatableBanana = bananaOne as Equatable
    //I don't get the additional operations added to Equatable (!=)
    if bananaOne != bananaTwo { } //Error
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the error message says: an extension of a protocol cannot have an inheritance clause. Instead, you could make `MyData` protocol inherit from `Equatable` in the original declaration.

```
protocol MyData: Equatable {
    var myDataID: Int { get }
}
```

You could then extend add an implementation of `==` for types that conform to `MyData`:

```
func == <T: MyData>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.myDataID == rhs.myDataID
}
```

However, **I would highly not recommend this!** If you add more properties to conforming types, their properties won't be checked for equality. Take the example below:

```
struct SomeData: MyData {
    var myDataID: Int
    var myOtherData: String
}

let b1 = SomeData(myDataID: 1, myOtherData: "String1")
let b2 = SomeData(myDataID: 1, myOtherData: "String2")

b1 == b2 // true, although `myOtherData` properties aren't equal.
```

In the case above you'd need to override `==` for `SomeData` for the correct result, thus making the `==` that accepts `MyData` redundant.

Comment: Small follow up, I had assumed that whoever implemented  `MyData` must also explicitly implement Equatable. Eg. Implementing Equatable is a requirement for MyData (which is what I wanted to avoid).

The `BananaData` is obviously a contributed example, but thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Does this playground do what you want?  I made it based on what I understand from [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/) from WWDC 2015.

```
import Foundation

//Plain old protocol here

func == (lhs: MyData, rhs: MyData) -> Bool {
    return lhs.myDataID == rhs.myDataID
}

func != (lhs: MyData, rhs: MyData) -> Bool {
    return lhs.myDataID != rhs.myDataID
}

protocol MyData {
    var myDataID: Int { get }
}

extension MyData where Self: Equatable {

}


struct BananaData: MyData {
    var myDataID: Int = 1
}

func checkEquatable(bananaOne: BananaData, bananaTwo: BananaData) {
    //This compiles, verifying that BananaData can be compared
    if bananaOne == bananaTwo {
        print("Same")
    }
    //But BananaData is not convertible to Equatable, which is what I want
    //I don't get the additional operations added to Equatable (!=)
    print(bananaOne.myDataID)
    print(bananaTwo.myDataID)


    if bananaOne != bananaTwo {

    }

    //Error


}

let b1 = BananaData(myDataID: 2)
let b2 = BananaData(myDataID: 2)

checkEquatable(b1, bananaTwo: b2)

let c = b1 == b2  // Evaluates as true
```

Comment: If a struct property conforms to Equatable (using `==`), you automatically get the function `!=`. I was using `!=` to check if `BananaData` actually conformed to the `Equatable` protocol instead of just having a `==` method. So while that compiles for my test case, what I was really looking for was a way to implement `Equatable` for all `MyData` structs.

Comment: Hi @Kevin .  I don't know if this makes a difference, but I see that you get an error when you do this... `extension MyData : Equatable { }` but you do not get an error when you do a constrained protocol extension like this `extension MyData where Self: Equatable { }`